# Are unexported identifier package public in Golang?

Tags: go

As the subject says, are unexported identifiers `package public` in Golang? 
I read the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) but can't find anything. The compiler seems to treat unexported function names as file private (and not package public).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All top level constants, types variables and functions have package scope.  This includes unexported identifiers of these kinds. The exact [language from the specification is](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope):

> The scope of an identifier denoting a constant, type, variable, or
>   function (but not method) declared at top level (outside any function)
>   is the package block.

Imported package names are the only entity with file scope.